# Can the attr() read the attribute of a child element?

Tags: html, css

An `<img>` has a parent (`<div>`) and I want the parent to have the background image of the `img`'s `src` attribute (`assets/picture.png`). So I wanna try, if that's possible, to read out the attribute of the child (`img`) for the parent in CSS.

```css
/*pseudo css*/
div {
   background-image:url(attr(img src));
}
```

```html
<!--html-->
<div>
    <img src="assets/picture.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: no you cannot .. and even if you can you won't be able to use it inside url of background because it can be used only with `content`. By the way can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: attr() return only string so you can use only as a content.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to use JavaScript or jQuery for that. Here's a simple jQuery solution:

```
$("div").css("background-image", `url${$("div img").attr("src")}`);
```

Pure JavaScript (ES6):

```
document.querySelector("div").style.backgroundImage = `url${document.querySelector("div img").getAttribute("src")}`;
```

Pure JavaScript (ES5):

```
document.querySelector("div").style.backgroundImage = "url" + document.querySelector("div img").getAttribute("src");
```

Comment: the OP didn't add the JS/jQuery tag so it's wrong to assume he want a JS solution by adding those tags

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this with **JQuery/Javascript**:

```js
$("div").css({'background-image':'url('+String($("div img").attr('src'))+')'});
```

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
img{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="https://www.step-outside.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/doelgroep-levensvragen-en-zelfregie.jpg">
</div>
```

However, you can achieve a simular result by doing this with **CSS**. You make sure you scale the `img` attribute and make sure it is positioned in the middle of the div with `position: absolute;`, `left: 50%;`, `right: 50%;` and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

```css
div{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
div img{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.step-outside.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/doelgroep-levensvragen-en-zelfregie.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to add a class on each images and just add the url on your background like so

```
 <div class="background"><div/>


.background {
   background : url("./folder/img.jpg") 0 no-repeat;
}
```

for example

Comment: Don't you mean `.background` for the selector? I see no `<background>` to this...

Comment: @LucasLaurens you can edit your answer to correct it to prevent more downvotes.